# Is it one coast or two?

Tags: grammatical-number

If I'm discussing two segments of a contiguous coastline, should I use the singular or the plural?

For example,

> The Washington and Oregon<sup>1</sup> coast ...

or

> The Washington and Oregon coasts ...

For those not familiar with the Pacific Northwest, this is what the coastline(s) in question look like:

[image: Washington and Oregon Coast]

<sup>1</sup> It has come to my attention people from the Midwest and East Coast sometimes pronounce the state "*or-e-GONE*" (/ɔɹɛˈgɑn/). Please don't do this, the correct pronunciation is "*OR-e-gen*" (/ˈɔɹegən/).

Comment: Trying to prescribe pronunciation is about as effective as trying to get people to diet.

Comment: Interesting map. Has Idaho been abolished, and no one told me?

Comment: @AlanCarmack Well, sure, for lexical terms. But proper names have correct pronunciations.

Comment: @StevenLittman It's just outside of the area of the map, what do you mean?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Washington is about 1.5 times as wide (east to west) as it is tall (north to south).  Therefore, it should end somewhere around the H in its name.  Oregon's dimensions are similar.

Comment: @StevenLittman I live in Washington. This map is clearly distorted horizontally (I think it's SE's doing, not the map).

Comment: Technically, if anything, the distortion is imgur's fault.... but in this case, it's neither. The actual image (as found in Google) is already distorted: http://www.westcoast.fisheries.noaa.gov/images/maps_all/oregonwashingtoncoastalmap.jpg

Comment: @Azor-Ahai In the note at the foot of your question, you refer to the "East Coast" (singular). Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @TrevorD No, not at all.

Comment: Why not? How can the entire East Coast be *one* entity, but a contiguous section of the West Coast be multiple entities? (Please see my answer below.)

Comment: In the same way that "a forest" is one entity but it's made up of multiple entities: trees.

Comment: @TrevorD I'm not saying you're wrong, but just because a collection of something is a collective noun doesn't mean that its components can't be discretized.

Comment: But 'forests' & 'trees' are *different* entities: the analogy would be 'coast' v. rocks, stones, sand, cliffs, etc.. 'Coast' isn't a collective noun.

Comment: No, you're right, it isn't a collective noun. I don't know what to call it, hence my question. But, conceptually, you could put a blue, green, and a red picnic table end-to-end for a large picnic and nail them together. You could then tell someone "Here, put this potato salad on the table," and no one's going to get all pedantic and say "Which table?" when there's clearly just one. On the other hand, you could say "Phil brought over the blue and green tables." Obviously, this isn't perfect since the tables were once separate, but you get why referring to 14 "coasts" as the East Coast isn't ...

Comment: ... a slam-dunk argument.

Answer (score 5):

It's dealer's choice.  It's however you prefer.

If you want to refer to it as a singular entity, as one coastline that both states share, then you'd say "coast," but if you want to refer to them separately, then it's perfectly appropriate to say "coasts."

Here is a [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coast+of+California+and+Oregon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoast%20of%20California%20and%20Oregon%3B%2Cc0) for using singular "coast":

Here is a [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coasts+of+California+and+Oregon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoasts%20of%20California%20and%20Oregon%3B%2Cc0) for using plural "coasts":

You'll notice I switched the example to California and Oregon rather than Washington Oregon.  That was meant as no slight to Washington.  I simply knew that references to California's coastline would generate more hits.

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious from the answer, I don't think you can use the singular "coast" if the two coasts are not **contiguous**.  Washington and Oregon's coastlines **are** contiguous, but you *shouldn't* say "The California and Washington coast" for example, as these are two distinct things seperated by a large distance.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.  Since the OP's question specifically limited the question to being about "two segments of a contiguous coastline," I presumed that went without saying.  That is why my research also compared usage to the California's and Oregon's coastlines, which are also contiguous and thus can be equally construed as a singular coastline.

Answer (score 1):

In written English, I would say:

> the Washington-Oregon coast

But neither of your versions is incorrect.

Comment: Pedantically, you wouldn’t say anything in written English—you’d write it. ;-) But “the Washington–Oregon coast” is how I would most likely say it in speech and write it in writing, too. This also works with non-contiguous entities, of course, as long as they’re connected at some point: the Washington–Oregon coast is just a subsection of the Washington–California coast—which, ultimately, is just a subsection of the North and Central American coast (until 1914 the American coast).

Answer (score 1):

A coast or coastline is a geographical feature that exists independently of which state, country or other entity currently claims 'ownership' of it. For that reason, I would suggest that it should be treated as a *singular entity* and referred to as one **coast** or **coastline**.

For example, it would not be unusual to refer to *the British coast* or *the British coastline* in the singular ([see Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22british+coast%22)). If the entire British coast is regarded as a single entity, it follows that any contiguous sub-section of that must also be a single entity, irrespective of whether that contiguous section borders one country, or two or three countries (England, Scotland, Wales); or one county or several counties (counties are the main sub-divisions of England).

In practice, if the particular contiguous section of coast actually borders two or more areas with different names (as in OP's example), it is not unusual for the plural form to be used; it would be unlikely to be considered 'odd'; and it would be unlikely to be misunderstood. Nevertheless, I would argue that useage of the plural form in such cases would (strictly) be incorrect.